# SpriteKit Swift Positioning HUD

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, coordinates

I'm trying to position a simple black box to use as reference for my HUD elements for a game. But the positioning of it is always really off, mainly the y position of the box. I tried to position my hud box to be at the very top of the screen and to spawn the whole width, but the CGRectGetMaxY(screenSize) positions it at the very bottom of the screen.

```
var hudLayer = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(self.size.width, 200))
            hudLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1)
            hudLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(screenSize), CGRectGetMaxY(screenSize))
            hudLayer.zPosition = 100
            self.addChild(hudLayer)
```

How did I manage to get my maxY coordinate to be at the very bottom? I'm perplexed and have tried other methods of y-positioning (self.size.height). So far, I find myself having to multiply the CGRectGetMaxY(screenSize) by 3.6 to get it to the top, but I'd rather not.

Any explanation as to why my y-coordinates are incredibly off? I set the anchor point, so it should be using the upper-left corner to position itself. Another issue is that I can't make this look the same on the 4s. On the 4s simulator, the hud bar appears much lower, despite using screenSize to calculate relative position.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this, the question talks about iPad and iPhone but your problem could be the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451131/spritekit-coordinates-differ-between-ipad-and-iphone/29451330#29451330

Comment: As others have said, it looks like your scene is being scaled. To fix it see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25256339/2158465 . But if you want to keep your scene scaled the way it is you will need to position nodes relative to the view, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29171224/2158465

Comment: That second link is actually the most relevant to my issue since I also set the resolution at the start- except mine is in landscape view. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds like your `SKScene`'s size isn't the same as your `SKView`'s size. To fix this you should set your scene's size and scale mode:

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

The easiest place to set this is probably in your `GameViewController`, when you're setting up your `SKScene`. Alternatively though, you could set this in the `didMoveToView` method, in your `SKScene`.

Comment: Oh wow. That never occurred to me that that could be a problem, I always though it was automatically calculated. Thanks! I'll try this out now!

Comment: Yeah, the size of your scene will be whatever you've set it to in the scene's .sks file. Perhaps your problem will be something they fix in the future, but currently sprite-kit doesn't really support different screen sizes the way UIKit does.

Comment: I just changed it in my GameViewController and now everything is blown out of proportion. I'm going to see if I should just scale everything down in my code. Hope this works!

Comment: Did it work in the end? Were you doing anything do scale nodes up?

Comment: Not really. My code is set up like this guys's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161881/skspritenode-position-in-universal-game/29171224#29171224   So, in the end, it's a lot more work to resize everything by setting the skView size. But now I know that that's a thing. :)

Comment: Do you need to run your app on different devices then?

Comment: Nope. I think I'm getting closer to the solution. I have to convert the positioning of my UI to somehow be relative to the playable area that's on screen. I've been testing it out on XCode's simulator's since I don't have all that many devices to actually test it on.